# ChartJS options: Unable to retain options variable custom label font sizes when adding separate title option

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to follow the DRY method and currently have a bar chart. I created a variable named "chartOptions" which contain my legend, x and y axes label font size preferences. What I would like to do, is for each of this bar chart to retain my "chartOption" settings, but allow me to have specific title for this chart (as I plan on adding other uniquely named charts).

Currently, it appears that no matter the order I've placed these options, it will display the title and reset the label sizes to default. From the Options specifications of ChartJS I am unclear if this is a limitation issue - where only one chart "options" argument is allowed/if nesting is allowed or if I need to look at this under global definitions or somewhere else. (both of which I have tried - but maybe not implemented correctly?)

Any thoughts or input on this is appreciated. I have attached my chartjs code - with a chart that demos what I am experiencing.

```
// This variable stores the global configurations for Chart Options
// such as font-sizes, axes scales...etc.
var chartOptions = {
legend: {
    display: true,
    labels: {
        fontSize: labelFontSize
    }
},
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Quarter',
            fontSize: labelFontSize
        },
        ticks: {
            fontSize: tickFontSize
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Number of Calls', 
            fontSize: labelFontSize
        },
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            fontSize: tickFontSize
        }
    }]
}
}


// Create Bar chart
var barChart1 = document.getElementById("barChart1").getContext("2d");
var supportCallsChart1 = new Chart(barChart1, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Q1-18", "Q2-18"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "test dataset",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [5, 10],
    }]

},
options: chartOptions, // having the options title below overwrites my x/y axes labels & font sizes
options: { // removing this title option will allow chartOptions settings to occur     
title: {
    display: true,
    text: "2018 Test Title",
    fontSize: chartTitleFontSize
    }
}   
});
```